# cron js(ts) не запускает метод из класса

Tags: javascript, typescript, cron

Есть cron функция вне класса:

```
cron.schedule('1,10,20,30,40,50 * * * * *', function() {
    this.webHookActionsPipeline(pipelineQueue[0].mergeRequestUrl, pipelineQueue[0].username, pipelineQueue[0].status);
});
```

и метод в классе `webHookActionsPipeline(mergeRequestID: string, username: string, status: string)`

После срабатывания cron, выпадает ошибка TypeError: this.webHookActionsPipeline is not a function

Почему так происходит и как исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Он вызывает функцию в другом контексте. Используй стрелочную функцию или `bind`:

> ```
> function() {
> ```

```
() => {
```

ИЛИ

> ```
> });
> ```

```
}.bind(this));
```

Comment: ни так:
cron.schedule('1,10,20,30,40,50 * * * * *', function() {
    this.webHookActionsPipeline(pipelineQueue[0].mergeRequestUrl, pipelineQueue[0].username, pipelineQueue[0].status);
}.bind(this));
и ни так:
cron.schedule('1,10,20,30,40,50 * * * * *',() => {
    this.webHookActionsPipeline(pipelineQueue[0].mergeRequestUrl, pipelineQueue[0].username, pipelineQueue[0].status);
});
не помогло, та же ошибка

Comment: @РусланГорбунов, тогда не знаю.